# How to make the background of a react Modal solid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-modal

So I have just added a Modal from react-Modal to a page through a button click, the problem I am facing is when i click that button to make the modal pop up, it does but the content of the page the modal covers seeps through, so the Modal looks like this.
[image]

The table etc shouldn't be there, only a blank white screen.
Can anyone help me please?

Below is the first class where I click to show the modal.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)
<button onClick={() => { setShowModal(true) }} className="paddingNextButton float-right viewButtonHover btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary"> Next</button>
<ModalForm isModalOpen={showModal} closeModal={() => { setShowModal(false) }} />
```

Below is another class of the Modal itself.

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import { Overlay } from 'react-bootstrap'

Modal.setAppElement('#root')
function ModalForm({ isModalOpen, closeModal }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal}
                style={
                    {
                        overlay: {
                            backgroundColor: "grey"
                        },
                        content: {
                            color: "red"
                        }

                    }
                }
            >
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <p></p>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ModalForm
```

Comment: Inline styles like this should be merged with the default modal styling. However, that doesn't seem to be the case. For the sake of testing that idea, try adding `background: "#fff"` inside the `content` style.

Comment: Hey @MattU unfortunately that only changes the text to white, the background still seeps through. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Setting `background` changes the text to white? The `color` style is what sets the font color.

Comment: Oh my bad @MattU i read that wrong, i've added it and it doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see the problem now. You don't have a `Modal.Body`, or a `Modal.Header` for that matter. What you need should be something like this:

```jsx
<Modal isOpen={isModalOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal} style={{...}}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>
            Title
        </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <p>Modal body goes here</p>
    </Modal.Body>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks @MattU, I tried that and see some weird behaviour, now the entire screen is blank and i can't seem to get past that.